# Withdrew from PhD without dissertation, can I claim that I have PhD on my resume?

Tags: phd, all-but-dissertation

I attended Capella University from 2009-2016. I earned a Master's degree without any problems. I completed all of the coursework for the Ph.D. at the same university and spent two years in the dissertation program. Due to many hindrances by the university (Absenteeism of 4 dissertation chairs, Lack of guidance and direction/feedback and extremely slow response time- many weeks) I decided to withdraw from the university. My overall GPA for the doctoral program was a 3.8 and my total tuition was $185,000 for the two degrees.  The university issued me a Ph.D. completion of coursework certificate. Can I use Ph.D. as an earned degree on my resume and other credential necessary situations?

Comment: Correction, your total tuition was $185,000 for one degree and a coursework certificate - not for two degrees.

Comment: The dissertation/thesis is the "spine" of the phd. You categorically do not have a PhD, implying otherwise would most likely characterise fraud (IANAL, depends on the country). Bad idea all around tho.

Comment: You're pretty clear about the fact that you don't have a PhD before asking if you can tell people that you have a PhD.  Exactly what sort of answer were you looking for here?  Did you just need folks to tell you the obvious?

Comment: You can use the exact wording from the completion of coursework certificate to show what you did achieve. Just don't give the impression you completed the PhD.

Answer (score 22):

No, you cannot. Your GPA and the money you paid are irrelevant here – there is simply more to a PhD than coursework. What you can try to do is try to apply to another PhD program and see if they will waive the coursework requirements, as you have already completed them – I don't know if that's possible. But if you don't have a paper from your university with the words "PhD diploma" (or equivalent) on it, then you cannot say that you have a PhD without lying. If your (potential) employer catches you, they will be in a good position to fire you.

Comment: Consider that in many countries there isn't even any coursework in the completion of a PhD.

Answer (score 11):

Absolutely not. Unless you have a diploma, you do not have a PhD! There are certain rules you have to follow to get a PhD, including a dissertation and a defense. The fact that you feel slighted by the university does not mean that you can re-define what rules apply for you.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the previous votes that you cannot claim PhD on your resume. Future employers would be able to use this as a reason to fire you without any additional justification. Unfortunately, you are not alone in this situation. Approximately 50% of all PhD students leave before completing the dissertation. This is so common that many cite your level of degree work as an "ABD" degree -- ABD stands for all but dissertation.

You might consider giving the dissertation another attempt. You could re-enroll for the minimum dissertation hours and form a new (and possibly better?) committee. Most universities allow 7 years for PhD completion, so you may be able to get back into the program without too much hassle. You may not want to do this, but it is an option for you to consider.

Another consideration: if you want to work in academia, all that is required to teach undergraduate students is a masters degree. Many colleges and universities have an "ABD" category in their payscale -- meaning that your PhD hours would enable you to earn more money than another candidate with only a masters degree. (I live in Florida and am a professor at a 4-year college. The "ABD" category was added several years ago and seems to be growing in popularity here.)

Best luck moving forward.